# Handlebars and Node.js: {{#if !user}} Then Show Log In Button

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm creating a login validation app using Node.js, Express, and Handlebars for the templating engine.

If there is no user logged in, I want my dashboard to display a "Log In" button. If a user is logged in, I don't want it to show. I tried this without having logged in...

```
{{#if user}}
    <a type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" href = "/users/login">Log In</a>
{{/if}}
```

Funny thing is, this hide the element. Then when I corrected the code to what it should be... This...

```
{{#if !user}}
    <a type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" href = "/users/login">Log In</a>
{{/if}}
```

I get this error,

[image]

I've never used handlebars before so I'm kind of shooting blind. Any help appreciated in advance!

Comment: You'll want to use the built in helpers. In this case, instead of saying `{{#if !user}}` you should use `{{#unless user}}`. http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html - you can also create your own helpers: http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html

Comment: @KeplerlO how do you get the user? To me, it is saved in localStorage. SO how can I have handlebars look if the user exist in localStorage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either deliver the `user` variable in its opposite state from the start or you could try to use `{{#unless user}}`.

http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html

Comment: how can I get the user if it is saved in localStorage. In other words, how can I have handlebars look if the user exist in localStorage?